# Alternatives to percentage change?

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling, descriptive-statistics, games

You can have the same mean but different standard deviation. Or the same standard deviation but a different coefficient of variation or 1 over signal-to-noise ratio or whatever. (I think  that's the same as different mean.)

**Question**: Is there a similar 'alternative' to percentage change?

**Context**: This is based on my previous question:

[Can you do hypothesis testing when instead of a 'sample' size you have 'actual' size? Alternatively, how would you use statistics to compare means?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561590/can-you-do-hypothesis-testing-when-instead-of-a-sample-size-you-have-actual)

(The context of the ff is chess / 9LX engine evaluations.)

I thought the 7% difference between the numbers 0.1913 and 0.179 might be 'significant' (whether 'practically' or 'statistically'; see the answer in the question) :

$(0.1913-0.1790)/0.1790 = 0.06871508379 \approx 6.87 \% $, almost $7\% $

But it was pointed out to me that:

> This percentage doesn't tell the whole picture or even close: there's a 200% difference between +0.01 and +0.03 but they're hardly distinguishable

I think I need some way to kinda **'boost' the 7%**, as in make the 7% a bigger number to show its importance and a way to **'nerf' the 200%**, as in make the 200% a small number to show its non-importance.

Well simply multiplying the percentage change with the original value gives me the absolute change. Maybe multiplying percentage change with new value?

7% x 0.1913 = 0.013391

200% x 0.03 = 0.06

Eh doesn't quite work... but at least we did bring down 2.00 to 0.06. That's a start maybe?

Comment: If you don't care about relative change why do you use %? Say, \$0.01 to \$0.03 is 200% but it's \$0.02, so why not just use \$?

Comment: You've asked many questions related to the same problem. As far as I can tell, there is not a statistical question here. You are simply comparing the engine evaluation between two sets of chess starting positions. What you seem to be stuck on is appropriately conveying the *meaning* of that engine score difference. In a standard game of chess, with certain engines, a +1 evaluation difference is the equivalent of a pawn. That's usually how you assign meaning to chess evaluations, by mapping to a difference in material.

Comment: @Tim oh absolute difference instead of percentage difference? but 0.1913-0.179 = 0.0123 < 0.03-0.01=0.02 ?

Comment: @statsplease i know ok. i'm not n00b. i used to be 1900 on chesscube. and how can i possibly ask all these questions about 9LX if I'm a n00b? (well i'm certainly chess openings but i'm not a n00b otherwise.) ughh...anyway...

Comment: @statsplease my goal is making meaning out of the 7%. Clearly 200% is way bigger than 7% but 0.03 and 0.01 and too small individually for anyone to really care. mean while 0.1790 and 0.1913 are huge. the biggest sesse eval is 0.57, a little over half a pawn. 0.1913 is really close to half way 0..57/2=0.285. so anyhoo i need to boost this 7% by showing that it's from big numbers and nerf the 200% by showing it's from small numbers. Hence, I'm asking for some equivalent of coefficient of variation or signal-to-noise for percentage change.

Comment: Gasai, nerf? Some readers will know this subculture jargon, bur others won't. I fear you're losing many readers there.

Comment: You've said that percentages are not meaningful; okay, I believe you. But you have not explained why absolute differences are not meaningful. You also haven't said why it would be inadequate to just write to your intended audience the explanation you've tried to give to us about how they should compare the 0.01->0.03 change with the 0.1913->0.179 change. You're stuck on this idea of "boosting" and "nerfing" but why are you even starting from percentage change to begin with?

Comment: @Jen well...i guess absolute differences are meaningful...hmmm...idk it's like this. i just wanted to say that in chess90 white has on average a 7% higher advantage compared to chess870. i'm trying to use this 7% as an argument to say chess90 bad chess870 good. The other guy told me 0.03 vs 0.01 has a 200% higher advantage. soooo your suggestion is to just skip percentage difference and go with just absolute difference?

Comment: I haven't intended to suggest anything. You are the one that knows this data and what measures are meaningful. I'm just pressing you to justify your choice to use percentage at all.

Comment: @Jen that's fair...idk...i just learned about percentage changes in 2ndary school and then i figured to use it now...?

Answer (score 1):

If the actual numbers are important rather than the percentage difference, then report the actual numbers. And if it's helpful to report the differences, report those too.

Like:

| before | after | change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1913 | 0.179 | -0.0123 |
| 0.01 | 0.03 | 0.02 |

And if it's important for the reader to understand that a difference of 0.02 has no practical significance, write that out for them, like, "In the context of ___, a difference of 0.02 or smaller is of no practical significance."

Comment: thanks but i mean ...you know Gasai how like you can have the same mean but different standard deviation? or the same standard deviation but a different coefficient of variation (or that's the same as different mean?) ? i'm thinking something like that. i need to like...use the smallness of the numbers 0.01 and 0.03 to nerf this 200% thing and then use the largeness of the numbers 0.1913 and 0.179 to boost this 7% thing.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know what you're talking about. But it sounds like you know what you want to do.

Comment: I really don't. :| it's like 5 and 10 have the same average as 3 and 12 but different standard deviation right? here's the absolute difference is about the same 0.0123 vs 0.02 but the percentage differences are 7% vs 200%. percentage difference provides 1 way to differentiate the 0.0123 and the 0.02, but this 'favours' the 0.02. is there another way to differentiate the 0.0123 and the 0.02 in a way that 'favours' the 0.0123?

Comment: Jen edited post to hopefully be clearer